# every rank 2 oriented matroid is realizable

Tags: reference-request, matroids

Does anyone know where I can find the proof for why every rank $2$ oriented matroid is realizable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One can find a proof of this result in Section 3.2 of Jürgen Bukowski's [Computational Oriented Matroids](https://books.google.at/books?id=0_Tp4jaK9j8C&pg=PA74&dq=%22The%20basic%20rank%202%20case%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiwZ-C0J7QAhVLXBoKHZB9DGoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20basic%20rank%202%20case%22&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

http://math.gmu.edu/~lawrence/m689/l4.pdf

This link has the steps to proving that all rank 2 oriented matroids are realizable. It leaves many details as exercises, but walks through the basic outline of the proof.

Comment: According to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926582/proof-that-rank-2-oriented-matroids-are-realizable), your link has gone stale. If you can update the link, that would be good.