# proof that rank 2 oriented matroids are realizable

Tags: reference-request, matroids

In many documents about oriented matroids, it is stated as an observation that every rank 2 oriented matroid is realizable. However, I did not find any document where the proof is given.

Do you know any reference where this proof is written?

Thank you!

P.S. This question has already been asked here: [every rank 2 oriented matroid is realizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581923/every-rank-2-oriented-matroid-is-realizable)
However, the link provided in the answer is not valid anymore

Comment: There's a new answer at that question now. (The same as was posted here.)

Answer (score 0):

One can find a proof of this result in Section 3.2 of Jürgen Bukowski's [Computational Oriented Matroids](https://books.google.at/books?id=0_Tp4jaK9j8C&pg=PA74&dq=%22The%20basic%20rank%202%20case%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiwZ-C0J7QAhVLXBoKHZB9DGoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20basic%20rank%202%20case%22&f=false).